# Undesired rerender of the child component in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Could you explain please why in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-platform-hde3w) child is rerendered on each 'test' button click? It doesn't use the new fields, that are created in click handler. How to fix it?

The source of the child component:

```html
<template>
  <span>
    <slot class="hello" v-bind="fields.test"></slot>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject: ["fields"],
  updated() {
    console.log("update child");
  }
};
</script>
```

The source of the parent component

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <Test v-slot="data">
        Current value: {{ data }}
    </Test>
  <button @click="test"> test </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Test from './Test.vue';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Test
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      fields: this.fields
    }
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      Vue.set(this.fields, Math.random(), Math.random())
    }
  },
  updated() {
    console.log("update parent");
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fields: {
        test: []
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, the re-render is expected since a template binding changes.  Here's why:

- The `updated` hook runs whenever a component re-renders
- A component re-renders if a binding in its template changes
- The child component in your example binds to `fields` in its template (from `provide`)
- `fields` changes when you run the `test` method
- I'm guessing Vue can't detect when only a specific property changed (i.e. `fields.test`) so it re-renders if `fields` changes at all, to be safe.  That's probably for the same reasons you have to use `Vue.set` in the first place (property change detection).

You could fix this by only using `provide` on the property itself:

```js
provide() {
  return {
    test: this.fields.test
  };
},
```

In the child:

```
inject: ["test"]
```

In the child template:

```
<slot class="hello" v-bind="test"></slot>
```

Since `fields` is no longer used in the child template, it won't re-render when fields changes.